# Adding multiple repositories in build.gradle : android

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to manage all the repositories in to one tree and tried the following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-android-sdk' }
    maven { url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven {
        url 'http://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeAndroidSDK-SNAPSHOT'
        credentials {
            username 'phonepe_android_sdk_snapshot_0_1_0@phonepe'
            password 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
   compile 'phonepe.sdk.android.snapshot:merchantSdk:0.5.9.1'
   compile 'in.juspay:ec-android-sdk:1.1.6'
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
   }
   compile project(':PayWithAmazon')
}
```

i tried to build the code and it alway says failed to resolve all the dependencies  which i have added as shown in the code above.

If I declare all these repositories separately and ran the build and it is successfully building the project without any issue. I dint understood where exactly I am making the mistake.
Please help in understanding the issue.

Below is working fine if i have added these repositories separately

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
// For Fabric
repositories {
  jcenter()
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
//For Localytics
repositories
    {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public' }
    }

//For JusPay
repositories
    {

        maven {
            url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-   android-sdk'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/'
        }

    }

//for Phone Pe staging
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   maven {
      url "https://jitpack.io"
   }

maven {
    url "http://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeAndroidSDK-SNAPSHOT"

    credentials {
        username 'phonepe_android_sdk_snapshot_0_1_0@phonepe'
        password 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks- Yakub.

Comment: What do you mean by _separately_?

Comment: I think 
`repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-android-sdk' }
    maven { url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven {
        url 'http://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeAndroidSDK-SNAPSHOT'
        credentials {
            username 'phonepe_android_sdk_snapshot_0_1_0@phonepe'
            password 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    }

}`

should be in project build.gradle and not in this build.gradle

Note: there are 2 build.gradle's

Comment: @Pulkit: thanks for your suggestions but i have edit my question and added the working script which is in the same build.gradle.

Comment: @Opal: Edited my question.

Comment: I just checked that the issue is not with the way that i added the repositories instead it is because of the plugin what i have used: apply plugin: 'com.android.feature' if i have the plugin type (apply plugin: 'com.android.application')then i am able to build. is there any specific configuration that needs to be added? as i have converted my existing application to become a feature module as part of the instant apps